# Word Press Function to Retrieve the URL from a Multisite?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Word Press multi site with 2 sites, and I want to provide a link on the main site to the second site.

If I use `get_site_url();` it returns a link to the main site.

I tried doing this -

```
switch_to_blog(2); 
$link = get_site_url(2);
restore_current_blog();
```

But `$link1` returns the main site url still.

Is there a function to retrieve the url for the 2nd site?

Comment: Where exactly are running this code?

Comment: @brasofilo in my header.php file. I want to create a link to the second site, and would like to avoid using the URL and use a function if possible